# MySQL, created view does not save data and return 0 rows

Tags: mysql, view

I have SQL script:

```
CREATE VIEW sports90_100 AS
select correctness, VoteUP 
from commentstable c, articles a
where a.category = 'sports' and c.articleID = a.ID and c.correctness between 90 and 100 
ORDER BY correctness;
```

I am trying to create view which contains two columns: correctness and VoteUP. When I run just select clause from script it returns result, but when I am trying to create view by using the same select an then see data from created view like this..

```
 select * from sports90_100;
```

It returns 0 rows.
Where is the problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: If the query runs without the view, then it should return the same thing using the view.  Perhaps the `view` is in a different database or you are making a mistake interpreting the results or the view already exists and you are ignoring the error when creating it.

Comment: Do "EXPLAIN EXTENDED select * from sports90_100; show warnings;" to see what "final" query mysql executes.

Comment: The view is in the same database. Interesting is that view works and returns data without a.category = 'sports' statement. It is important statement to return correct data, how to manage this?

Comment: The view works perfectly, see this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e87a/1 Just do `DROP VIEW sports90_100` and recreate it from sratch. Are you really sure that select clause from this view running alone gives any results ? Maybe you are running some different query than the query in the view ?

Comment: It is confusing, but yes, the select alone works perfectly. But in combination with view it does not return anything